# Meteor Session.get() returning correct value but with extra whitespace / lines

Tags: javascript, meteor

I can't figure out why `Session.get()` is returning the expected property, but with some strange formatting.

In the console:

```
>Session.get('department');
```

returns (e.g.):

```
"
    7
  "
```

My objects don't seem to have any strange formatting in their properties. For example:

```
>Suppliers.findOne();
```

Returns

```
Object {_id: LocalCollection._ObjectID, 
        vndrLongNm: "*ERSACE", 
        venOpCode: 7, 
        supSiteNum: 7839748, 
        vndrTypeCd: "B"…}
        _id: LocalCollection._ObjectID_str: "547f4cfe2979008172bb7071"__proto__: LocalCollection._ObjectID
        deptDesc: "980-DIRECT GIRLS 7-14"
        supSiteNum: 7839748
        venDptNum: 980
        venOpCode: 7
        venResNum: 58794
        vndrLongNm: "*ERSACE"
        vndrTypeCd: "B"
        __proto__: Object}
```

Which looks right to me. Note that the value for `venDptNum` is a number – `980` – with no apparent extra spacing or extra blank lines.

The following mongo query returns a sorted list of unique `venDptNum`s:

```
Template.departments.helpers({
  departmentNames: function() {
    var everything = Suppliers.find({}, {sort: {venDptNum:1}}).fetch();
    var justDepartments = _.pluck(everything,"venDptNum");
    return _.uniq(justDepartments);
  }
```

It does return the list and populates a dropdown with the list of `venDptNum` properties, as intended. I then take that selection and set it as the session variable value for `department`:

```
Template.departments.events({
  "change .department-selection": function(e, t){
    return Session.set("department", $("[name=departmentNames]").val());
  }
});
```

I have almost the exact same code running [here](http://dynamic-dropdowns.meteor.com/). If you're curious, try running `Session.get('department');` and see that it's returning the value as expected.

[Note: this was at least part of the problem I discovered while answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387222/meteor-dynamically-filter-dropdown-when-another-dropdown-is-selected) question.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error in the template:

```
<template name="vendorNames">
  <select name="vendorNames" autocomplete="off" class="form-control vendor-name-selection">
    {{# each vendorNames}}
    {{> vendorName}}
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

<template name="vendorName">
  <option name="vendor">
    {{vndrLongNm}}
  </option>
</template>
```

The `vendorName` template was forcing a new line and adding that (apparently) into the value. Solution was changing the formatting to:

```
<template name="vendorNames">
  <select name="vendorNames" autocomplete="off" class="form-control vendor-name-selection">
    {{# each vendorNames}}
    {{> vendorName}}
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

<template name="vendorName">
  <option name="vendor">{{vndrLongNm}}</option>
</template>
```